# Django Debug Toolbar

Tags: django

boa noite!! Alguém pode me ajudar com esse erro, estou tentando utilizar o debug_toolbar:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/sara/dev/virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/sara/dev/virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/sara/dev/virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/sara/dev/virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/sara/dev/virtual/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named notificationdebug_toolbar
```

Eu estou seguindo esse tutorial: [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: Sara, em vez de instalar daquela forma, você pode simplesmente instalar usando `pip`. No seu virtualenv, instale `pip install debug_toolbar`, e adicione no `INSTALLED_APPS` o `debug_toolbar`, apenas isso é suficiente para rodar.

Comment: Olá  Orion, bom dia! fiz exatamente o que você falou, mas o mesmo erro persiste.

Comment: Não sei porque ele não está conseguindo importar esse módulo, sei que o `debug_toolbar` funciona apenas com Django 1.7 pra cima, o repositório original é esse: https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está faltando uma vírgula separando as aplicações `notification` e `debug_toolbar`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
       ...
     notification,
     debug_toolbar
       ...
)
```